# syslog-ng match rule match but should not

Tags: logging, match, message, syslog, syslog-ng

I have a problem with syslog-ng matching rule.
I have  3 filters with match rule to specify tags

my conf :

```
source s_all {
    syslog(
            ip(0.0.0.0)
            transport("udp")
    );
};
filter flt_apache_access {
    match('[apache2]') and
    level(info);
};
filter flt_apache_error {
    match('[apache2]') and
    level(err);
};
filter flt_history {
    match('[history]');
};
destination dst_apache_access {
    file("/data/syslog/${.metadata.client}/${HOST}/apache_access-${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}.log");
};
destination dst_apache_error {
    file("/data/syslog/${HOST}/apache_error-${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}.log");
};
destination dst_history {
    file("/data/syslog/${HOST}/history-${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}.log");
};
log {
    source(s_all);
    filter(flt_apache_error);
    destination(dst_apache_error);
};
log {
    source(s_all);
    filter(flt_apache_access);
    destination(dst_apache_access);
};
log {
    source(s_all);
    filter(flt_history);
    destination(dst_history);
};
```

if I try to send log which match flt_history like that :

```
logger -n 127.0.0.1 -d -p local6.info [history] TEST MATCHING histo
```

I have 2 logs files created with same content :

```
root@Syslog-center:/data/syslog/127.0.0.1# cat apache_access-2018-06-27.log
Jun 27 11:46:09 127.0.0.1 opalanque: [history] TEST MATCHING histo


root@Syslog-center:/data/syslog/127.0.0.1# cat history-2018-06-27.log 
Jun 27 11:46:09 127.0.0.1 opalanque: [history] TEST MATCHING histo
```

And my syslog-ng debug / verbose is :

```
2018-06-27T11:49:52.823930] Incoming log entry; line='<182>1 2018-06-27T11:49:52.823717+02:00 Syslog-center opalanque - - [timeQuality tzKnown="1" isSynced="1" syncAccuracy="110500"] [history] TEST MATCHING histo'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.823977] Setting value; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', name='HOST_FROM', value='127.0.0.1'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.823983] Setting value; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', name='HOST', value='127.0.0.1'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.823988] Setting value; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', name='SOURCE', value='s_all'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.823994] Filter rule evaluation begins; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', rule='flt_apache_error', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/central.conf:36:26'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824004] Filter regexp node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', input='opalanque: [history] TEST MATCHING histo', result='match'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824008] Filter node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='match', type='regexp'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824011] Filter node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='not-match', type='level'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824014] Filter node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='not-match', type='AND'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824019] Filter rule evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='not-match', rule='flt_apache_error', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/central.conf:36:26'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824023] Filter rule evaluation begins; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', rule='flt_apache_access', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/central.conf:31:27'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824028] Filter regexp node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', input='opalanque: [history] TEST MATCHING histo', result='match'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824031] Filter node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='match', type='regexp'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824035] Filter node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='match', type='level'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824038] Filter node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='match', type='AND'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824041] Filter rule evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='match', rule='flt_apache_access', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/central.conf:31:27'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824052] Setting value; msg='0x7f8c9c005600', name='.metadata.client', value='mutu'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824057] Message parsing complete; result='1', rule='p_client', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/central.conf:12:2'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824088] Initializing destination file writer; template='/data/syslog/${.metadata.client}/${HOST}/apache_access-${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}.log', filename='/data/syslog/mutu/127.0.0.1/apache_access-2018-06-27.log'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824149] Filter rule evaluation begins; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', rule='flt_history', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/central.conf:41:21'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824155] Filter regexp node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', input='opalanque: [history] TEST MATCHING histo', result='match'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824159] Filter node evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='match', type='regexp'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824163] Filter rule evaluation result; msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='match', rule='flt_history', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/central.conf:41:21'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824168] Setting value; msg='0x7f8c9c0056d0', name='.metadata.client', value='mutu'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824172] Message parsing complete; result='1', rule='p_client', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/central.conf:12:2'
[2018-06-27T11:49:52.824189] Initializing destination file writer; template='/data/syslog/${.metadata.client}/${HOST}/history-${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}.log', filename='/data/syslog/mutu/127.0.0.1/history-2018-06-27.log'
```

I do not understand why there is this log line :

```
msg='0x7f8c9c0044e0', result='match', rule='flt_apache_access', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/central.conf:31:27'
```

I try to modify my filter like that :

```
match('[history]');
message('[history]');
match('[history]' value("MESSAGE"));
match('[history]' value("PROGRAM"));
program('[history]');
```

But all failed with the same behavior or without logging

Answer (score 0):

I found solution...

All problème provide from [ and ] characteres...
I changed my tag and with this configuration it's ok :

```
filter flt_apache_access {
    match('apache2') and
    level(info);
};
filter flt_apache_error {
    match('apache2') and
    level(err);
};
filter flt_history {
    match('history');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets need to be escaped with two backslashes, so use:

```
filter flt_apache_access {
    match('\\[apache2\\]') and
    level(info);
};
```